# How do I reset PYTHONPATH to "default" value in virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I was struggling with installing dependencies for an external library (the requirements were already fulfilled) when I read that I should check if the install path is in my PYTHONPATH. It wasn't, so I looked up how to add it.

I came across this answer, and typed the code straight into the Terminal (not `~/.bashrc`) before I finished reading.

> If you're using bash (on a Mac or GNU/Linux distro), add this to your ~/.bashrc
>
> `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"`

The path was I entered was `/usr/bin/python`.

Surprisingly this fixed all of my dependency problems.

**However**, since my Django project is dependent on a virtualenv, this ruined everything. I can no longer find how or where to restore my PYTHONPATH to.

I tried `export PYTHONPATH="/home/[username]/.virtualenvs/[env]/bin/python"` and also deleting the virtualenv with `rmvirtualenv`.

My next plan is to delete the project and pull again.

Comment: You misunderstood. It was supposed to be a question as I haven't solved it. I edited the title for clarity.

Comment: You pretty much break the idea of the virtual environment when using the system python library path. It would be much better to solve the dependency proplem instead of using a dirty workaround. So, what is the actual installation problem?

Answer (score 0):

> typed the code straight into the Terminal (not ~/.bashrc) before I finished reading. [...] I can no longer find how or where to restore my `PYTHONPATH` to.

`export`ed variables aren't sticky; you just close the terminal session to get rid of the variable set.

Your `PYTHONPATH` will be correctly set again once you re-activate your virtualenv in the new terminal session.

> The path was I entered was `/usr/bin/python`.

Adding an executable to `PYTHONPATH` fixing all of your issues is *very* surprising indeed.

Answer (score -1):

At the top of your Django `settings` module, you could include:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/your/dependency/path')
```

Comment: Added this to the top of my settings.py, no change.
`sys.path.append('/home/[username]/.virtualenvs/[env]/bin/python')`

Comment: As you're working inside a virtualenv, that path was already included in the `PYTHONPATH`. I assumed you were going to add `/usr/bin/python`, or any other directory with your dependecy there.